# Solving $u_t = (f(t)-1)u_x$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, transport-equation

Good afternoon,

Here's the question I'm currently working on:

---

Determine the solution of the following transport equation:
$$u_t = (f(t)-1)u_x \space \space \space ,\space x \in \mathbb{R}, \space 0 < t < T $$

$$ u(x,0) = x $$

---

I've already solved for some arbitrary functions of $f(t)$, and I've concluded that the solution should look something like this,

$$ u(x,t) = x + \int_{0}^{t} f(s)-1\space ds $$

I've also calculated the characteristic curves for this problem and I can't develop the equations:

$$\frac{dx}{ds} = -(f(t)-1) \implies x(s) = - \int_{0}^{s} f(t) - 1 \space dt$$

$$\frac{dt}{ds} = 1 \implies t(s) = s + \alpha \space , \space \alpha \in \mathbb{R} $$

Could I have some hint on how to follow up and come up with the solution for the problem? I also don't have any particular information on the function $f$.

Thanks for reading this far!

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti I took, for example, $f_1(t) = t$ and $f_2(t) = t^2$, and I noticed the "pattern" in between the diferent solutions. I know this isn't mathematically rigorous or correct, but it was a big assumption I made. I'm sorry if I didn't make myself clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characteristics are paths of the form $x(t;x_0)=x_0 - \int_0^t f(s) - 1 ds$. You then have $\frac{d}{dt} u(x(t;x_0),t)=0$. Therefore $u(x(t;x_0),t)=u(x(0;x_0),0)=x_0$ so it suffices to find $x_0(x,t)$. But you know $x=x_0 - \int_0^t f(s) - 1 ds$ so $x_0=x+\int_0^t f(s) - 1 ds$ as desired.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't need the full solution for it, but much obliged!